# ritual function/destroying an NFT

Tags: tokens, nft

As I am totally new to coding and NFTs and was researching about the topic, I was curious how the ritual-function in Mitchell Chans 'Digital Zones of Immaterial Pictorial Sensibility' exactly operates. Source Code is here:

https://github.com/mitchellfchan/IKB/blob/master/IKB.sol

thanks for your help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which part of the function is not clear?

Comment: I wonder how it gets burned. Does it get send to the 0x0-adress?